# If include? == false

Tags: ruby

I have an array and a string:

```
$header = ["Date", "Time", "Site Name", "Computer Name"]
columnName = "esfjk sdhf sdf"
```

and I am checking if `$header` contains `columnName`:

```
return if $header.include? columnName == false
```

The condition above always returns `true`, and the code carries on, even though the array doesn't contain the string.

I also have the same issue when `$hash` is a hash and `recordNum` is a number such as `99999999` which is not in it, and I do:

```
return if $hash.has_key? recordNum == false
```

Any reason for this happening?

Comment: `some_expression_that_is_always_boolean == false` or `some_expression_that_is_always_boolean == true` are redundant. When you have that, there is a code smell. Just by this fact, your code is terribly bad.

Comment: My apologies for my 'terribly bad' code, the fact that I only started learning Ruby 2 days ago and have not learned all the keywords (such as 'not' and 'unless') yet are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @sawa was unnecessarily rude, and I wouldn't call your code terribly bad, but the point is valid. In almost any language, the point of comparisons is to generate a boolean value, so when you already have one of those, using it in a comparison is a bit overkillish.

Comment: You should avoid using global variables (those that begin with `$`) whenever possible (which is nearly all the time).

Comment: I understand this, I do that when using other languages that I know well such as; C#, Java, JavaScript etc. @Andrew Marshall How would I go about not using them whenever possible, I thought it would be easier to have 1 global array which I use in all different functions instead of rewriting it out 10 times.

Comment: @ThomasOwers Perhaps you can encapsulate those functions into an object and store the array as an instance variable within the object. To put it in perspective: I’ve written untold amounts of Ruby code and don’t think I’ve ever used a global variable outside of debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precedence.

```
$header.include? columnName == false
```

is interpreted as

```
$header.include?(columnName == false)
```

that is, usually,

```
$header.include?(false)
```

which is false.  So what you want to do instead is this:

```
$header.include?(columnName) == false
```

But in your particular case, I would do this (thanks, Alex Wayne):

```
return unless $header.include?(columnName)
```

And if you do that, then you can go back to the parentheses-less form:

```
return unless $header.include? columnName
```

Comment: How about `return unless $header.include?(columnName)` Nice and simple.